# OpenVPN problem wih routing between subnets

Tags: docker, openvpn, route

Hi i have set up a system like this
[Situation Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XStVW.png)

Here I have the server network at 192.168.255.1/24 and 2 subnets 10.0.0.1/24 and 10.0.1.1/24. I want these to be able to call a client that is in the server space.

What I did is create this openvpn.conf

```
server 192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0
verb 3
key /etc/openvpn/pki/private/VPN.greenhive.at.key
ca /etc/openvpn/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/pki/issued/VPN.greenhive.at.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/pki/dh.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/pki/ta.key
key-direction 0
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun

proto udp
# Rely on Docker to do port mapping, internally always 1194
port 1194
dev tun
status /tmp/openvpn-status.log
topology subnet
client-config-dir ccd

user nobody
group nogroup
comp-lzo no
client-to-client

### Route Configurations Below
route 192.168.254.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.0.1.0 255.255.255.0

### Push Configurations Below
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "comp-lzo no"
push "route 192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.255.1"
```

Currently there are no "iptables" rules, but i also tried it with this.

> -A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 192.168.255.0/24 -i tun0 -j ACCEPT

also Forwarding is active

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

client-to-client is also active. Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem here? i can ping inside each subnet (so from 192.168.255.1 to 192.168.255.2) but not between them (from 10.0.0.1 to 192.168.255.2). The other way (from 192.168.255.2 to 10.0.0.1) works not after adding `push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.255.1"` to the client config

EDIT: I found that the route `push "route 192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.255.1"`is never pushed. The error is "RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable" however i can not see any conflicting entry in ip routes

```
root@127:~# ip route
default via 192.168.88.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100
10.0.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1
192.168.88.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.88.154 metric 100
213.136.74.54 via 192.168.88.1 dev eth0
```

EDIT
I just tested on a different machine and found that the routes are added without error but that push route adds a route to the interface en0 instead of utun3. thus a ping tells me network not reachable.
`push "route 192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.255.1"`

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
default            192.168.88.1       UGScg             en0
10/24              10.0.0.2           UGSc            utun3
10.0.0.2           10.0.0.2           UH              utun3
192.168.255        192.168.255.1      UGSc              en0
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of your other question [Openvpn unable to ping server, route says network unreachable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/701222/100397)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Openvpn unable to ping server, route says network unreachable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/701222/openvpn-unable-to-ping-server-route-says-network-unreachable)

Comment: TO be honest I made both questions because i did not want to ask both things at once. The problems are different. one is the problem that the routes are not created, and this one is a general problem that also exists on a client where the routes seem fine. So would you say it is the same?